# TSQL - Difficult Grouping

Tags: sql-server, grouping, window-functions

Please see fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e6768/2

I have data, like below:

```
DRIVER  DROP
1       1
1       2
1       ReturnToBase
1       4
1       5
1       ReturnToBase
1       6
1       7    
2       1
2       2
2       ReturnToBase
2       4
```

I am trying to group my data, so for each driver, each group of return to bases have a grouping number.

My output should look like this:

```
DRIVER      DROP           GROUP
1            1              1
1            2              1
1            ReturnToBase   1
1            4              2
1            5              2
1            ReturnToBase   2
1            6              3
1            7              3
1            ReturnToBase   3               
2            1              1           
2            2              1
2            ReturnToBase   1   
2            4              2
```

I've tried getting this result with a combination of windowed functions but I've been miles off so far

Below is what I had so far, it isn't supposed to be functional I was trying to figure out how it could be done, if it's even possible.

```
SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition BY Driver order by Driver Desc) rownum,
    Count(1) OVER (Partition By Driver Order By Driver Desc) counter,
    Count
    DropNo,
    Driver,
    CASE DropNo 
       WHEN 'ReturnToBase' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS EnumerateRound
FROM 
    Rounds
```

Comment: Can you please add the sql you have tried so far. Looks like Row_Number should fit here

Comment: You're looking at some kind of recursive LEAD LAG common table expression to accomplish this.

Comment: There is a sequential identifier also, sorry I should have included that in the example.

Comment: The drop 6,7 should be 7,8 or is the sample correct?

Comment: Can you please add the sequential identifier for future readers?  Also it will be needed in the answer, so might as well use the right column name.   Does it help if you try `Partition by driver Order By SequentialColumn`?

Comment: are there always three rows per Group? and has ReturnToBase to be in each Group?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the following query:

```
SELECT id, DRIVER, DROPno, 
       1 + SUM(flag) OVER (PARTITION BY DRIVER ORDER BY id) -
       CASE 
          WHEN DROPno = 'ReturnToBase' THEN 1 
          ELSE 0 
       END AS grp       
FROM (
  SELECT id, DRIVER, DROPno, 
         CASE 
            WHEN DROPno = 'ReturnToBase' THEN 1 
            ELSE 0 
         END AS flag
  FROM rounds ) AS t
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/19cb3d/2)

This query uses windowed version of `SUM` with `ORDER BY` in the `OVER` clause to calculate a running total. This version of `SUM` is available from SQL Server 2012 onwards AFAIK.

Fiddling a bit with this running total value is all we need in order to get the correct `GROUP` value.

**EDIT:** (credit goes to @Conrad Frix)

Using `CROSS APPLY` instead of an in-line view can considerably simplify things:

```
SELECT id, DRIVER, DROPno, 
       1 + SUM(x.flag) OVER (PARTITION BY DRIVER ORDER BY id) - x.flag
FROM rounds
CROSS APPLY (SELECT CASE WHEN DROPno = 'ReturnToBase' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS x(flag)
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/19cb3d/10)

Comment: Perfect, I was way off. Thank you

Comment: You might want to consider using Cross Apply instead of an inline view if you want to alias a single calculation .. [for example](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/356003)

Answer (score 2):

Added a sequential ID column to your example for use in a recursive CTE:

```
with cte as (
select ID,DRIVER,DROPno,1 as GRP
FROM rounds
where ID = 1
union all
select a.ID
,a.DRIVER
,a.DROPno
,case when b.DROPno = 'ReturnToBase' 
      or b.DRIVER <> a.DRIVER then b.GRP + 1 
      else b.GRP end
from rounds a
  inner join cte b
    on a.ID = b.ID + 1
)

select * from cte
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/754a0/3)